# VB.Net Extract Part of a String Before Certain Character

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In VB.NET; I am trying to extract Part of a String Before Certain Character; this is very easy if you have that character once; like below:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, TextBox1.Text.IndexOf("/"))  
End Sub
```

The problem is that my string is a website address that I want to get the first part as below:

```
http://www.example.com/subfol1/subfol2/abcd.html
```

I want to get the homepage addres; i.e.:

```
http://www.example.com/
```

I tried the following code also:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Split("/"c)(0) 
    Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Split("/"c)(1) 
End Sub
```

But VB.Net always consider the first "/" and ignore the rest?!

I think the idea is to get the part of the string before the third "/", but I do not know how to do that?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the starting index past the http://

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(11, TextBox1.Text.IndexOf("/", 7) -15)  
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi prospector; I tried this code; it resulted in "www.sa" only?

Comment: Hi prospector; the updated code is working only for the example; but if you have different website address, it will be wrong; like (http:// www . exampleandtest . com/subfol1/subfol2/abcd.html)

Comment: hold on im testing it, ill get it in a minute

Comment: GREAT; you made it look so easy; thanks prospector. Accept and +1.

Comment: glad I could help, I've got a lot of experience with substring and I got to put it to use.

Comment: What if the address is shorter or longer. The example provided is an example not guaranteed. I would have looked at regex myself, just an opinion.

Comment: @Codexer It works regardless of the length as long as the url is prefixed with http:// and www.; it wouldn't be to different to change the code to work without www. and with https, but in the original post he/she asked for it to work with http://www.

Comment: Correct with www, but not all are. Therefore this would indeed break. Also I noticed that most newer browsers dont even have the http or https or www as part of the url anymore, well at least when navigating... Also it only gives you the text inbetween not all for ex: www.whatever.com

Comment: @Codexer for all we know, the op is only wanting to pull domains from a list of domains in an excel file. If it's not all needed then it's fine.